# ideas for a unique (or semi-unique) application of audio fingerprinting

Tags: project, audio-fingerprinting

I am a final year computer undergrad student looking for a unique (or semi-unique) application for audio fingerprinting, for my finally year project. My original idea was to have a program to figure out what song a user was humming, thru the use of audio fingerprint. But I did a search, and found out somebody had already implemented it (perfectly I might add). Any suggestions on how I can tweak it (it doesnt have to be TOTALLY new) or derive some thing along similar field will be VERY MUCH appreciated.

P.S. Thank you in advance.

(P.P.S. I don’t have to do a full implementation, just the core part or an essential part of my choosing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last.fm has an amazing API and song fingerprinting script. Maybe you could extend their app to do something different?